# Accept fixed number of arguments, or no arguments using a fixed number of defaults

Tags: python, argparse

I want to allow either 2 arguments, or 0 arguments and fall back to defaults. I thought that this should do it

```py
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('myargs', nargs=2, default=['foo', 'bar'])
```

However, this throws on anything but 2 arguments (the defaults are thus never invoked):

```py
print(parser.parse_args(['a', 'b'])) # 2 arguments accepted
print(parser.parse_args([])) # throws
```

My question is, (how) can this be done without extra code. I.e. I want to find something more elegant and more default *argparse* than for example this workaround:

```py
import argparse

def parse(args):

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('myargs', nargs='*', default=['foo', 'bar'])
    a = parser.parse_args(args)

    if len(a.myargs) != 2:
        raise IOError('Incorrect number of arguments')

    return a

print(parse([])) # defaults
print(parse(['a', 'b'])) # 2 arguments accepted
print(parse(['a', 'b', 'c'])) # throws (as excepted)
```

Comment: Can't you simply test `sys.argv` beforehand ? ìf (len(sys.argv) != 0 and len(sys.argv) != 2): raise ArgumentError`

Comment: @BigBro Thanks. That is indeed a fine option, but arguably not much different that mine. My question is really how to exploit *argparse* better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `argparse` an argument without prefix (the default prefix is `-` for abbreviation or `--` for full argument name) is considered as mandatory. So, if you want to have an optional argument you can do something like this:

```py
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--myargs', nargs=2, default=['foo', 'bar'])
```

In this case, if you do not pass any argument, it works like expected:

```py
print(parser.parse_args([]))

Namespace(myargs=['foo', 'bar'])
```

On the other hand, if you provide same values:

```py
print(parser.parse_args(['--myargs', 'a', 'b']))

Namespace(myargs=['a', 'b'])
```

An error will be raised if you pass the wrong number of arguments after `myargs`:

```py
print(parser.parse_args(['--myargs', 'a']))

usage: scratch_2.py [-h] [--myargs MYARGS MYARGS]
<your script name>: error: argument --myargs: expected 2 arguments
```

Another (longer) way is to define a custom action to parse the arguments:

```py
class CustomParsePositional(argparse.Action):
    """Action to parse arguments with a custom processing"""
    def __init__(self, option_strings, dest, nargs=None, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(option_strings, dest, nargs='*', **kwargs)
        self._custom_nargs = len(kwargs.get('default', []))
    def __call__(self, parser, namespace, values, option_string=None):
        if len(values) != self._custom_nargs:
            parser.error('Incorrect number of arguments')
        namespace.__setattr__(self.dest, values)

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('myargs', default=['foo', 'bar'], type=str, action=CustomParsePositional)
```

In this case the number of expected values is inferred by the number of items in the `default` argument of the `add_argument`. Here some examples:

```py
print(parser.parse_args(['a', 'b']))
print(parser.parse_args([]))
print(parser.parse_args(['a']))


Namespace(myargs=['a', 'b'])
Namespace(myargs=['foo', 'bar'])
usage: scratch_2.py [-h] [myargs [myargs ...]]
<your script name>: error: Incorrect number of arguments
```

And if you pass 3 values you get the an error as well:

```py
print(parser.parse_args(['a', 'b', 'c']))

usage: scratch_2.py [-h] [myargs [myargs ...]]
<your script name>: error: Incorrect number of arguments
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Very clear answer. Do I understand well that in the end things boil down to either changing the command-line API, or doing something like the work-around that I suggested in my question; as there is simply no other way in argparse?

Comment: I've updated the answer with a solution based on the customization of the action for an argument.

Comment: Amazing! Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Glad to help :)

Answer (score 1):

A brief description of how `argparse` parsing works might help.

Values are collected in a `namespace` object.  At the start of parsing, the `default` values are all placed in `namespace`.  Then as arguments are encountered in the user input they are parsed as specified in the `add_argument`, and the values placed in `namespace`, over writing the defaults.

Flagged arguments are parsed when the flag is seen, e.g. '--foo bar', but positionals like yours are required, and take the exact number of strings specified by `nargs`.  In this case it will use the 2 strings.  So for this definition, the `default` parameter is useless.

With `nargs='*'`, any number of strings satisfies it.  The case of 0 strings gets special handling, and puts the default in the `namespace`.

There's nothing in-elegant about adding checks after parsing.  The error message can be streamlined with:

```
if len(a.myargs) != 2:
    parser.error('Incorrect number of arguments')
```

Older parsers like `optparse` handled all flagged arguments, and returned the rest in an `extras` for you to handle.  `argparse` handles those `extras`.  Handling positionals with a fixed `nargs` is easiest.  One positional with a variable `nargs` generally works fine, but it is hard to use more than one.  If you specified two actions with `*`, how is the parser supposed to allocate strings?

Yes, you can define custom `Action` classes to handle special cases, but often the result is less elegant (IMO) than simpler post-parsing checks.  I don't give extra points for cleverness :)

Comment: Thanks! Very much clarifying, and thus very much appreciated!